# Bash: How to use 'find' for a file with specific extension but that it would also give its previous directory

Tags: bash, find

I'm quite stuck on a piece of code where I have to use 'find' to locate all files with a specific extension but that the output would also give the particular directory that the specific file is located in.
For example:

```
find . -name "*.exe" -o -name "*.bat" -type f
```

I use this code to find all files with the extension `.exe` and `.bat` and the output it gives me is:

```
./test/test1/test2/hello.exe
```

My question is would it be possible for the command to only give me the output like this:

```
test2/hello.exe
```

As in only the directory that the file is located in.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Maybe look at `-printf` and/or postprocess the resulting lines.

Comment: Pipe to a `sed` or `grep` command that extracts the part you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -name "*.exe" -o -name "*.bat" -type f | grep -Po '[^/]*?/[^/]+$'
```